# Is correct to say "solutions published tomorrow"

Tags: grammar, tenses

Yesterday I got "The Telehraph" newspaper and was examining the puzzles section when caught a sentence: "Solutions published tomorrow". Is this a correct construction? Or maybe newspaper's slang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of *JOURNALESE*.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary

***Journalese***

noun

: a style of writing held to be characteristic of newspapers

In newspaper headlines it's typical to use the Past Participle for traditional passive constructions (in your case: ''published'' instead of  'will be published') or the bare Infinitive for traditional active constructions (for example: the headline ''President visit Germany tomorrow'' instead of 'The President will visit Germany tomorrow').

Comment: Much more common would be “president to visit Germany tomorrow, no? That is, the full infinitive. Otherwise writers would normally make that “visits.”